# How to add a string array to a node in xml c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a node `<name></name>` where I put name. Now I want to put an array of names there.

Comment: How would you like to put array of names? Comma separated or you mean <names><name></name></names> structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlNode node = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(path);            

foreach(string x in val)
{
    XmlNode subNode = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, subNodeName, null);
    subNode.InnerText = x;
    node.AppendChild(subNode);
}
```

path is the path to the node in xml

Answer (score 2):

If you must put ARRAY to this object you can use some syntax like:

```
<name>
 <element>X</element>
 <element>Y</element>
</name>
```

or use a some serialization to string and pack to it.

```
<name>X,Y</name>
```